# Postgres: how to grant an user to add more users to a group

Tags: postgresql, privileges, role, usergroups

So I know in postgres a group is nothing but a role. But I'll still use groups here.

Say I created a group called my_group as superuser.

I am user user_1.

I want to give user_1 permission to add more users into my_group.

What is the command I need to do as superuser to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Use `GRANT WITH ADMIN OPTION` to do that:

```
GRANT my_group TO user_1 WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

More info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html).